# next.js, after export relative path of images become absolute

Tags: next.js

In next.js app after build and export relative path of images become absolute and when I try to open up the index.html there are no images ...

I'm using for example: `<img src='/images/tools/js.svg' alt="javaScript" />`
My images are in public/images folder
Nex.js version latest 13.4.16, but I attempted previous versions as well
Node.js v18.17.1

next.config.js is:

```
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    images: {
        unoptimized: true,
      },  
}
```

I tried unoptimized, Image element from Next, assetPrefix in config, played with pathes but there is nothing helped me
Help me)

Comment: <img src='/images/tools/js.svg' alt="javaScript" />